# Can't push change to branch created by admin

Tags: git, gitlab

So I'm studying Gitlab . Pretending to be the admin and the collaborator at the same time.

As Admin:

- pushing the project
- create branch "`myslavebranch`" using the button provided on the website.

As collaborator side:

```
$ git init 
$ git config --global user.name "theslave"
$ git config --global user.email "theslave@gmail.com"
$ git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:theadmin/masterproject.git
$ git pull
$ git clone git@gitlab.com:theadmin/masterproject.git
```

Yes, now I get the project into my repo. Modifying the file , adding, commiting. Now switch to the branch

```
$ git checkout myslavebranch
$ git push
```

And I got:

```
remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project.
remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What's the problem here? Do the admin need to give the permission first? Is it about SSH? wrong step? I want to push my edited version to the branch the admin made. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions of the repository.

I think you need to be at a developer, a maintainer, or owner to push code. Like configuration is necessary for contributors to push code in the repository in general. For example, in most cases, the admin should add users to the repository as "developers", or better roles to push code. Or admin allows anyone to push code.

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html

Other troubleshooting involves checking your SSH public key if it's properly registered in gitlab and linked with your account.

Also, please check if the branch made by the admin is protected.

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html

Comment: Do you mean like the admin first need to assign permission for the branch?